# xdebug_break and start_with_request in the php.ini file - not working as expected

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

Per the docs for `start_with_request = no` at https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#start_with_request :

> You can still start a Function Trace with `xdebug_start_trace()`, Step Debugging with `xdebug_break()`, or Garbage Collection Statistics with `xdebug_start_gcstats()`.

My php.ini:

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so"
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=192.168.1.121
xdebug.client_port=9000
xdebug.start_with_request=no
xdebug.output_dir=/opt/cris/profiling/grind_files
xdebug.profiler_output_name=callgrind.out.%p 
xdebug.profiler_append=0
xdebug.log = /var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log
xdebug.log_level = 0
```

I have a `xdebug_break()` statement that does not turn on
the debugger in PhpStorm as expected when the execution passes over it.

Per the docs, I'd expect Xdebug to kick into play when it hits the `xdebug_break()` command with php.ini setup  like this, and I'd start step debugging in PhpStorm.

I want to disable Xdebug from sending debugging output which is why I `start_with_request` is set to `no`.  Once the code hits the `xdebug_break()` THEN start emitting debugging output so that PhpStorm goes into Step Debugging mode.  If there is a different way to achieve this I'm all ears

What did I miss?

Comment: 1) Is your PhpStorm is listening for incoming debug connections at that time (the phone handle icon)? Show a screenshot of the whole IDE window when you expect the debug to be working. 2) What OS you have got there (where IDE is running). Please make sure that it's PhpStorm (and not another process) that listens on Xdebug port. 3) Please enable xdebug log (seems to be enabled already .. but will log nothing due to log level = 0), try to debug and provide the log here -- it will tell if it tries to connect to the IDE (if at all) and what the response is.

Comment: 1) yes, but as I note in the description the problem isn't that xdebug it isn't working, it's that it's working too much. I want more control over when it emits debugging info.  The phone is all green and breakpoints are being hit, log being filled correctly based on level setting.

2) xdebug is running on a Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS server, PhpStorm is on Win7pro.

3) log level is currently set to 10 as part of my config change testing.

Your reply, thx, reads like you are looking at this as "I can't connect to Xdebug" - which isn't the case

Comment: Thanks. **Your comment made it mode clear (at least to me)** -- that it's all working just the `start_with_request = no` does not work as expected. I've tried it locally (PHP 8 x64 on Windows 10) and can confirm that with not setting the `start_with_request` (so it's `default`) it will start the debug session and PhpStorm breaks after `xdebug_break()` line. At the same time with `xdebug.start_with_request = no` Xdebug does nothing.

Comment: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions#xdebug_break -- *"If no debugging session is active yet, **and xdebug.start_upon_request is set to trigger**, then Xdebug will attempt to start a new debugging session first."* This paragraph explains current behaviour.  @derick should give you a more authoritative answer on that.

Comment: Based on the above you may do: 1) leave on `default` (i.e. do not set any value for that param); 2) if you have concerns that somebody else can trigger the debug session -- perhaps control that via `ENV` or change the trigger name/value ("debug me" flag) to some unique name that is hard to guess.